# Change and cycle through images onclick in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, onclick, cycle

I am just trying to cycle through all my images and then do nothing at the end via an onclick function. However I am having trouble. Any suggestions would be great.

```
<SCRIPT>

var quizImagesB = new Array(); 

 quizImagesB[0]="images/dratiniB.png"
 quizImagesB[1]="images/parasB.png"
 quizImagesB[2]="images/mewB.png"
 quizImagesB[3]="images/doduoB.png"
 quizImagesB[4]="images/meowthB.png"
 quizImagesB[5]="images/cloysterB.png"
 quizImagesB[6]="images/ponytaB.png"
 quizImagesB[7]="images/articunoB.png"
 quizImagesB[8]="images/flareonB.png"

function updateImgB(){
for(var i=0; quizImagesB<.length; i++){
var url = 'url(' + quizImagesB[i] + ')';    //alters css
document.getElementById('pkmnImg').style.backgroundImage=url;
 }
}

</SCRIPT>

<style type="text/css">
#pkmnImg
{
background-image: url(images/charmanderB.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
text-align: center;
width: 400px;
height: 450px;
margin-top: 10px;
margin-left: 15px;
}</style>

<FORM>
 <INPUT TYPE="Button" VALUE="Change the image source" onClick="updateImgB();">
</FORM>

<div id ="pkmnImg"></div>
```

Comment: hey Alex, for me at least it is not very clear what your desired outcome is. What exactly do you want to do with these images?

Comment: is it that on each click you want the page to display the following image?

Comment: thanks for the response. In plain english i want the following to happen
img1> *click* > img2> *click*>img ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok this should work. Instead of looping through the array you want to increase the value of `i` by 1 on each click, allowing you to cycle through the array this way - see jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ffd7tmwy/1/

Javascript:

```
    var quizImagesB = new Array(); 

     quizImagesB[0]="images/dratiniB.png"
     quizImagesB[1]="images/parasB.png"
     quizImagesB[2]="images/mewB.png"
     quizImagesB[3]="images/doduoB.png"
     quizImagesB[4]="images/meowthB.png"
     quizImagesB[5]="images/cloysterB.png"
     quizImagesB[6]="images/ponytaB.png"
     quizImagesB[7]="images/articunoB.png"
     quizImagesB[8]="images/flareonB.png"

     var i = 0
     function updateImgB(){
        var i = i + 1;
        var url = 'url(' + quizImagesB[i] + ')';
        document.getElementById('pkmnImg').style.backgroundImage=url;
      }
```

HTML

```
<div id='pkmnImg'></div>
<form>
    <input type="button" value="Change the image source" onClick="updateImgB()">
</form>
```

Comment: is it filtering through the images for you? it works for me, but when I try and do it on jsfiddle it isnt working. Can you check your console and try console.log(i) to check if the value is increasing on the click?

Comment: ah I got the jsfiddle working, see above. Excuse the brett the hitman hart images

Comment: is that what you are looking to do?

Comment: No probs, my pleasure