# jQuery: loop to change image issue

Tags: jquery, loops

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 
    $('.box').on('click', function () {
      var images=["http://www.themadcatlady.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/2013-11-0212.15.22.jpg","http://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Black-Cat-Pictures-12.jpg",
"http://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Black-Cat-Pictures-12.jpg"];
   
          for(i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            $('#image').attr("src", images[i]);
        }
    });

});
```

```css
.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row first-row">
            <div class="box col-md-2">
                <img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/fe/3c/61/fe3c61a811ad7aa24c7fcd8ff8586436--vampire-masquerade-vampire-art.jpg" class="img-fluid" id="image">
            </div>
        </div>
```

I have this simple jQuery code to change the source of an image on 'click'. But the src only gets updated once and I can't see what I'm missing... Can someone help me out? The code:

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.box').on('click', function () {
      var images=["img-1",img-2", etc];

          for(i=0;i<images.length;i++){
            $('#image').attr("src", images[i]);
        }
    });
```

The HTML:

```
<div class="row first-row">
            <div class="box col-md-2">
                <img src="img/image.jpg" class="img-fluid" id="image">
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You are iterating over all images on each click so it will always display the last one in the list.

Comment: Note that you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552) to produce runnable code here on Stack Overflow so that people don't have to go to another site. Also, you're looping through an array of images all within a single click, which means it will always end up on the last one.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change and cycle through images onclick in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29722742/change-and-cycle-through-images-onclick-in-javascript)

Comment: As it stands, on each click your handler will load `images.length - 1` different image sources into the image in a loop. This will occur extremely fast, probably not be visible to the naked eye, and will result in the visible image source being the final image source (i.e. the `images[images.length - 1]` source value).

Comment: for loop runs very fast, the UI will not update on every iteration. You will only get the last one. You need to look at using a timer to adjust the images.

Comment: using a timer like a setTime interval?

Comment: I've checked the suggested duplicated, increased the i value, var i = i + 1, but still doesn't work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vampire image is not part of the images array and you have 1 image repeating at index 1 and 2

The following code is looping through all the three images in the array. Add the vampire image to the images array and it will start looping as well.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var currentImage = 0;
    $('.box').on('click', function () {
      var images=["http://www.themadcatlady.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/2013-11-0212.15.22.jpg","http://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Black-Cat-Pictures-12.jpg",
"http://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Black-Cat-Pictures-12.jpg"];

    console.log("currentImage", currentImage);
        if(currentImage === images.length)  currentImage = 0;
            console.log("displaying image at " + currentImage);
        $('#image').attr("src", images[currentImage]);
        currentImage = currentImage + 1;

    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

First, The vampire images in not part of images array. Second, instead of looping through the whole array, Why don't you find the index of the the current source in the array and then just change the src attribute to the next array and when you reach the end, set the current index to -1.
Here's the code for it.

```
$(function(){
        var images=["http://www.themadcatlady.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/2013-11-0212.15.22.jpg","http://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Black-Cat-Pictures-12.jpg",
                              "http://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Black-Cat-Pictures-12.jpg"];    


        $('.box').on('click', function () {
            var currentIndex = images.indexOf($("#image").attr("src"));
            if(currentIndex === images.length - 2){
                currentIndex = -1;
            }
            $("#image").attr("src", images[currentIndex+1]);
        });

    });
```

Comment: thank for the answer, but i have only to mark one as valid...:)

Answer (score 0):

As has been mentioned, you can't loop over the array, you must increment with each click.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
 var images = new Array();
 images[0] = "http://www.themadcatlady.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/2013-11-0212.15.22.jpg"
 images[1] = "http://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Black-Cat-Pictures-12.jpg"
 images[2] = "http://tailandfur.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Black-Cat-Pictures-12.jpg"

var i = 0;
$('.box').on('click', function () {
    $('#image').attr('src', images[i]);
i++;
});
```